# Invalid JWT token for New subaccount in SaaS

Tags: sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-sdk, sap-cloud-foundry, sap-business-technology-platform

We are working on SaaS application development on SAP BTP ,facing very strange issue ,with new subaccounts  ,after publishing our application through SaaS registry service and implementation of all call backs and including dependency call back ,when we are creating a new Tenant Subaccount and doing a subscription facing issue in login steps below ---

- subscription is working fine and able to generate tenant specific url.
- When user login to application unbale to call any backend service api via logged in User as XSUAA is unable to authenticate as JWT signature is not valid -

***"<error_description>Cannot verify signature of access
token</error_description> invalid_token"***

- Same workflow works fine with old subaccounts created some time back for testing purposes.
- Facing issue with newly created Subaccounts for tenant.

Please help.

Thanks,
Siddharth

Comment: Hi Jain, sounds very much like a known issue with SDK 2.0 that is currently deprecated. What SDK version do you use? With the latest SDK version you shouldn't experience any issues: https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/release-notes-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java

Comment: Thanks Kovalyov ,we have migrated to new sdk version long back and we are on follwing version - v3.35.0.

Comment: also we tried updating Security jars to latest version but no luck-com.sap.xs2.security:java-container-security:0.33.18
com.sap.xs2.security:security-commons:0.33.18

Comment: XSUAA changed how JWTs for tenants are validated for newly created tenants some time back. The behaviour you describe very much looks like this is causing the issue. But the SDK adapted to this change long before v3.35.0, so you should not be affected.

I think we need more information to tackle this. Could you please share the dependency tree, the full stack trace of the error, the source code of your tenant onboarding and if possible debug log output.

Comment: Adding to the answer by Matthias, I'd recommend posting a GitHub issue here for easier tracking of the investigation: https://github.com/SAP/cloud-sdk/issues/new/choose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SAP Business Technology Platform has changed the way of Tenant's JWT validation in the first half of 2020. Instehttps://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/release-notes-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java#3161ad of using well-known and only one URL to get the validation key, it's now relying on the `jku` field and `issuer` to make sure every Tenant has a URL to fetch a key for the JWT validation.

The SAP Cloud SDK version [3.16.1](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/release-notes-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java#3161) and above should fully support this validation mechanism. This means that the SDK version you use should be perfectly fine.

There could be edge cases where the application logic might require an update. That's why I suggest you create an issue [here](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-sdk/issues/new/choose) and provide the following information:

1. Since when the issue started affecting you? Was it working a week before and broke just now? Or you haven't added new Tenants in a while and now it's breaking?
2. Dependency tree of you App
3. Please, provide detailed exception stack trace or logs to identify the root cause.
4. Send us the code snippet where you believe things fail.

When we can make it reproducible, solving this should be rather straightforward.
We are happy to update this thread when a solution is found so that community can benefit.

Looking forward to the detailed [issue](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-sdk/issues/new/choose) and reproduction steps.